Help! How can I fix my Canon Sureshot that keeps rewinding?
extremely new to film photography, picked up this camera from a thrift, was working fine (for context I had no film in). I was testing all the features, flash, etc. And it was working perfectly, though I believe I switched the film rewind button or something while I pressed the shutter button and now a motor in it will not stop spinning. I took the batteries out to see if that'll fix it but no, it did not. I am gonna send this video to show the issue and also the manual for it I found online, all help would be appreciated. [Also thought I'd mention it shows S on the frame counter, I don't know it that'll help]
https://streamable.com/ho86az
https://www.cameramanuals.org/canon_pdf/canon_af_35m_ii.pdf

This appears to have broken (or at least, untrustworthy) electronics. How much did it cost? I guess thrift stores don't do refunds? Bring it to your local friendly electronics recycling point, and buy a different camera.
